# change data in JSONObject in jsonArray

Tags: json, arrays

I have jsonArray as follows

JSONArray childern as

```
 [{"id":2,"label":"w","remoId":135},
  {"id":3,"childern":null,"loc":146,"label":"Loc-w"},
  {"id":4,"childern":null,"loc":147,"label":"Loc-newjk"}
 ]
```

i want to change childern key of JSONObject having id=3 to childernArray where

```
  childernArray is  [{"id":6,"label":"w"},{"id":7,"label":"w"}]
```

I want following output

```
[{"id":2,"label":"w","remoId":135},
 {"id":3,
        "childern":[{"id":6,"label":"w"},
                    {"id":7,"label":"w"}],
         "loc":146,"label":"Loc-w"},
 {"id":4,"childern":null,"loc":147,"label":"Loc-newjk"}]
```

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.reduce() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
jsonArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  if(currentValue.id == 3) {
    currentValue.children = childrenArray;
  }
  previousValue.push(currentValue);
  return previousValue;
}, []);
```